# When dows 'this' keyword points ? In rumtime or compile time?

Tags: spring, dependencies

**How does this work in this condition? If I have to initialize brandrepository in every method at compilation how can I make it**

```
@Autowired
private BrandRepository brandRepository;
@Override
public Page<BrandDTO> getBrandList(int page, String sortBy, String orderBy) {
    BrandRepository brandRepository = this.brandRepository;**Does this code execute once or multiple times**
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, 10, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.valueOf(orderBy), sortBy));
    Page<BrandEntity> result = brandRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return result.map(brandEntity -> toDTO(brandEntity));
}
```

Comment: The code you marked will run whenever `getBrandList()` is called.  I don't think I understand your question?  `this` refers to the instance

Comment: Do this points each and every time the method is called?

Comment: `this` refers to the instance of the class this method is in, so yes.  You don't even really need that line though, you can just use `this.brandRepository` instead of `brandRepository` since you're assigning `this.brandRepository` to a variable.

Comment: How can I assign it just once in the method and not change it?

Comment: You can either assign it in a constructor or only assign it if `brandRepository` is null